# bash script and awk to sort a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

so I have a project for uni, and I can't get through the first exercise. Here is my problem:
I have a file, and I want to select some data inside of it and 'display' it in another file. But the data I'm looking for is a little bit scattered in the file, so I need several awk commands in my script to get them.

```
Query= fig|1240086.14.peg.1

Length=76
                                                                  Score     E
Sequences producing significant alignments:                          (Bits)  Value

 fig|198628.19.peg.2053                                              140     3e-42


> fig|198628.19.peg.2053
Length=553
```

Here on the picture, you can see that there are 2 types of 'Length=', and I only want to 'catch' the "Length=" that are just after a "Query=".
I have to use awk so I tried this :

```
 awk '{if(/^$/ && $(NR+1)/^Length=/) {split($(NR+1), b, "="); print b[2]}}'
```

but it doesn't work... does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Does it HAVE to be awk, you can you use anything?

Comment: well it's preferable to use awk, but I'm opened to anything haha

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input. See [ask] and in particular the part about providing a [mcve].

Comment: The best thing you can do is sorting with `awk(1)` and making computations with `sort(1)`.  And to go to stackoverflow once you don't know how to do such things.  Try calculating `pi` number with `ls(1)` that's a real challenge!!!  Read `grep(1)` as it will solve all in one shot.  Name is unfortunate, but it's the tool you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how Awk works.  It reads a line, evaluates the script, then starts over, reading one line at a time.  So there is no way to say "the next line contains this".  What you *can* do is "if this line contains, then remember this until ..."

```
awk '/Query=/ { q=1; next } /Length/ && q { print } /./ { q=0 }' file
```

This sets the flag `q` to 1 (true) when we see `Query=` and then skips to the next line.  If we see `Length` and we recently saw `Query=` then `q` will be 1, and so we print.  In other cases, set `q` back to "not recently seen" on any non-empty line. (I put in the non-empty condition to allow for empty lines anywhere without affecting the overall logic.)

Comment: thank you!!! really good idea that is going to help me throughout my project, and thank you for the explanation

Comment: it's better to arrive just in time than to be around looping for years!!!

Answer (score 0):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^Length=/ && r~/^Query/{ sub(/^[^=]+=/,""); printf "%s ",$0 }
     NF{ r=$0 }END{ print "" }' file
```

---

- `NF{ r=$0 }` - capture the whole non-empty line
- `/^Length=/ && r~/^Query/` - on encountering `Length` line having previous line started with `Query`(ensured by `r~/^Query/`)

Comment: @tripleee, the crucial moment is that `Length ...` line and `Query ...` line should be adjancent

Comment: thank you for your answer! can you explain to me what "r~" means exactly?

Comment: @janedoe `r` variable contains previously captured line (`r=$0`)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what you want for the first part of your question:

```
$ awk -F'=' '!NF{next} f && ($1=="Length"){print $2} {f=($1=="Query")}' file
76
```

but idk what the second part is about since there's no "data" lines in your input and only 1 valid output from your sample input best I can tell.

Comment: thanks!! can you explain what does "!NF{next} f" mean?

Comment: about the second part, data1 is the query and data2 is the length, I extract them with two separate awk commands, and when I put them in a file, it 'appends' data2 at the end of data1, but i would like data2 to be one tab away on the side of data1

Comment: as requested earlier, please edit your question to include whatever it is you're trying to describe wrt these "data" items in your sample input/output or remove all mention of that from this question and ask a new question.